# change list within list to dataframe for statistical analysis

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have the following list structure:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
a b c d
1 2 3 5
[[1]][[2]]
a b c d
2 5 3 5
[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
a b c d
8 2 3 5
[[2]][[2]]
a b c d
7 5 3 1

str(fit)
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : Named num [1:20] 1 2 3 5 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:20] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
  ..$ : Named num [1:20] 2 5 3 5  ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:20] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
```

The content is each list within list is numeric in structure.

I want to change it in dataframe, something like the following:

```
NA NA a b c d
 1  1 1 2 3 5
 1  2 2 5 3 5
 2  1 8 2 3 5
 2  2 7 5 3 1
```

(`NA` however, can be replaced by `v1` `v2` if each dataframe has to have a name.)

I wonder if this is possible.

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the data

Comment: This is usually done with do.call(rbind, YourList) but without seeing your data ...

Comment: @user1945827 won't work with list of lists.  It may be `do.call(rbind,do.call(c, fit))`

Comment: Well, have I actually done research before asking this question? Yes. Do I actually understand the solutions? No.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand and what is exactly isn't working for you?

Answer (score 7):

This is somewhat an expansion to what was offered in the comments while utilizing the `rbindlist` function from the `data.table` package (you need the latest version on CRAN)

```
library(data.table) # v 1.9.6+
rbindlist(
  lapply(fit, function(x) {
    temp <- do.call(rbind, x) 
    cbind.data.frame(V2 = 1:nrow(temp), temp)
   }
  ), idcol = "V1")
#    V1 V2 a b c d
# 1:  1  1 1 2 3 5
# 2:  1  2 2 5 3 5
# 3:  2  1 8 2 3 5
# 4:  2  2 7 5 3 1
```

If you always have two elements with a single row in each list you could avoid creating `temp` and just do `cbind.data.frame(V2 = 1:2, do.call(rbind, x))` instead

---

**Data**

```
fit <- list(list(c(a = 1,b = 2,c = 3,d = 5), 
                 c(a = 2,b = 5,c = 3,d = 5)),
            list(c(a = 8,b = 2,c = 3,d = 5), 
                 c(a = 7,b = 5,c = 3,d = 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in base R, you can do:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(seq(length(fit)), 
               function(x){
                  cbind(v1=rep(x, length(fit[[x]])),
                        t(sapply(seq(length(fit[[x]])), 
                                 function(y, x){
                                     c(v2=y, fit[[x]][[y]])
                                 }, x=x)))
                }))
#     v1 v2 a b c d
#[1,]  1  1 1 2 3 5
#[2,]  1  2 2 5 3 5
#[3,]  2  1 8 2 3 5
#[4,]  2  2 7 5 3 1
```

I wouldn't bet on the efficiency though...